# Get all list in site without hidden list

Tags: sharepoint

I want to get all lists in site using sharepoint that without hidden list. Because i know that, when we list all lists, we will receive all including hidden list. Please help me, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [PnP PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplist?view=sharepoint-ps).

```
#region Variables 
$Username = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
$Password = "password" 
$siteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee" 

#endregion Variables

#region Credentials 
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials

$lists=Get-PnPList | ?{$_.Hidden -eq $false}
foreach($list in $lists){
    Write-Host $list.Title +"Hidden:" $list.Hidden
}
write-host "done"
```